# teradata rank event data based on group where group has events

Tags: teradata

I have a dataset where im trying to generate a sequence number in teradata
In the dataset below, an order (550) is subjected to a number of modifications in a shop (10 in total)
The final column ShopSequence is what I want to achieve where the when the order is moved to a different shop the ShopSequence number increments by 1
So this dataset reads as subjected to 10 modifcations across 4 shops
There are many such orders

```
Order,   Shop,  SequenceNumber,     ShopSequence            
550,     AA,      1                 1
550,     AA,      2                 1
550,     AA,      3                 1

550,     BB,      4                 2
550,     BB,      5                 2
550,     BB,      6                 2
550,     BB,      7                 2

650,     CC,      8                 3
650,     CC,      9                 3
650,     CC,      10                3
```

I tried a number of OLAP configurations but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SequenceNumber asc, Shop asc) AS shop_row_number`,
`RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Shop asc  ORDER  BY SequenceNumber ASC`

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `DENSE_RANK OVER (ORDER BY Shop asc)` instead.

This works as long as there's no 2nd group of rows with the same `shop` value.

Edit:

According to your comment values might repeat, so this works for repeated groups, too, but needs nested OLAP-functions:

```
select ...
   sum(flag) -- calculate the rank
   over (partition by Order 
         order by SequenceNumber
         rows unbounded preceding) as ShopSequence
from
 (
   select ...
       -- flag the rows where a new group starts
       -- 'min...' can be replaced by LAG in TD16.10+
      case when min(Shop)
                over (partition by Order 
                      order by SequenceNumber
                      rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) = Shop
         then 0 
         else 1
    end as flag
 ) as dt
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth. Thanks very much. Unfortunately sometimes the shop id might repeat because the order number might go back to it for additional manufacturing

Comment: @JohnSmith: Added a 2nd query for repeated groups :-)